Ejecutar una acción cuando se cierre una pestaña (tab) o página
básicamente necesito que al cerrar una pestaña o página web se genere una acción por ejemplo que llame mediante ajax a un archivo PHP y este a través de una base de datos indique la hora que el usuario cerro la página. Lo de Ajax y PHP lo tengo hecho, lo que no puedo hacer es que al cerrar la pestaña o página me genere la llamada a ajax. He navegado y leído sobre el tema y tengo entendido que ya no se permite el método "unload" de javascript por temas de seguridad y solo he logrado trabajar con "beforeunload" pero no me sirve para lo que necesito ¿alguien lo ha resuelto?.
El siguiente código permite solo un aviso "¿Abandonar sitio?" con 2 botones  Salir y Cancelar  la idea es que si presionan el botón "Salir" me llame al código Ajax y este a PHP.
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      console.log("beforeunload DETECTADO");
      return 'Dialog text here.';
    };
});


y si cierra el navegador? y si lo fuerza al cierre? y si apaga directametne la pc?? esto suena a esos tipicos problemas que en realidad no tienen solucion (ya lo viste) y que deberian ser tratados de otra forma... por ejemplo, con un worker que tenga un keep alive..,.

Ninguna solución garantiza capturar todos los eventos de cierre, especialmente si el usuario apaga directamente la PC o fuerza el cierre del navegador. como dice la persona que comento arriba ... ni siquiera los worker ... de lado del cliente ...

otra opcion basado en overheat sería implementarlo en el lado del servidor con heartbeat o WebSockets ... pero esa es otra historia ... si te interesa cambia el enfoque y lo vemos ...
